# How do you keep an object in the same place as you change devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm very new to Xcode and objective-c and started working on a simple game. As I was editing the storyboard, I added multiple labels, buttons, and a background image. The size is compact width and regular height for all iphones in portrait. Now, when I run this in iPhone 6, the simulator shows everything exactly how I want it and where I want it (and the size is just perfect), however when I go to Iphone 5, 5s, or 6s, either the background image is too large or too small and all the objects go EVERYWHERE randomly and the buttons don't work. When I saw the tutorial, it worked perfectly for them... I learned about constraints and used them, they worked great until a bunch of errors saying 'Ambiguous' over and over again and ended up ruining simulator taking 3 hours to fix! Is there any way to set the object in the same place and same proportions (maybe ratio to size) no matter what device you change it to?

Using Xcode 7.2
Goals: Same size objects in iPhone 5,5s,6,6s,6+, and6s+

Please help me

Comment: u need to use Auto layouts. for IOS

Comment: @Shravan They are all already on, but the problem is unfazed

Comment: This should be helpful http://www.developerinspirus.com/autolayout/. It's a crash course in autolayout

Comment: u need to apply constraints

Answer (score 0):

You have to use autolayout for this purpose. You can set constraints to resize the contents. Hope [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) tutorial will help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this with constraints finish it up, it's all starting to work out now

Answer (score 0):

U need to apply constraints 
just go through the following links:

[apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html)

[short tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2)
to get started

[WWDC videos](https://developer.apple.com/search/?q=mysteries%20of%20auto%20layout&type=Videos) for a better understanding

Comment: Thanks, it's all starting to make more sense now

Comment: just accept the answer or upvote it.. :) by the way try to use apple develper as much as possible... for better understanding u can even use the wwdc videos .. ill edit the answer and add the link.

Comment: welcome.. :) dont forget to vote up/ accept the answer :)

Comment: I'd want to, but I'd first need 15 reputation

Comment: haha by accepting the answer u can increase ur reputations... so u can do that. The more activities u do in here the more reps u get.